# Rewriting urls with mod_rewrite - GET variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I found out I could make clean urls with mod_rewrite. I managed to make pages like **/home.php** viewable by visiting **/home** (without .php).

Now, I'd like to turn **view_album.php?album_id=23** into **album/23**

This is the code I use, but sadly it's not working:

```
Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /beta/
RewriteRule ^album/(.*)/ view_album.php?album_id=$1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the point in "cleaning" urls? how /home is better than /home.php?

Comment: **album/23** doesn't have a trailing slash, while your patter `^album/(.*)/` requires one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /beta/
RewriteRule ^album/([0-9]*)$ view_album.php?album_id=$1
```

and make sure you only rewrite if a noting or a number follows `album/`, so your can access your images, which may be in a folder named album.